# Have onEndEditing fire when user presses submit button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

This is kind of a weird issue, but I'm using text input's onEndEditing function to populate an array useRef. The problem is when the user presses a completely separate "Submit" button, it does not count that as onEndEditing and the array does not contain the value from the last text input. I've tried manually calling Keyboard.dismiss() which does have onEndEditingFire, but populates the array too late. Any help would be appreciated. TYIA

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by using a promise on Keyboard.dismiss(). Keeping the post up in case others run into this problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).